# Run method after doPost is complete

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way to call a `method()` after each `doPost(req, res)` without having to rewrite `method()` at the end of each `doPost` block in every single servlet?

Comment: Use a servlet `Filter`.

Comment: You can implement the filter to only run your method if the request method is a POST. See the javadoc of `HttpServletRequest` for how to get the request method.

Comment: The answer below shows how to do that. Just add an `if` block that checks if the request method was a `POST`.

Comment: A `Filter`'s `doFilter` method runs _around_ the execution of a servlet (if you want it to). See the comments in Luiggi's answer. When you call, `chain.doFilter(..)` somewhere in that call, your Servlet gets invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to the answer of [JeremiahOrr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22461658/1065197), you must also verify that you're performing a POST request on your servlet, otherwise the code will also be executed for other requests like GET. This would be a more concrete example:

```
public class YourFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)  throws ServletException { }
    public void destroy() { }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // whatever you want to do before doPost
        chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if(httpRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
            //whatever you want to do after doPost only HERE
        }
        //whatever you want to do after doGet, doPost, doPut and others HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because it is after `FilterChain#doFilter` call, which internally calls `Servlet#service` which internally calls `doPost` or `doGet`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably using a servlet Filter.

```
public class YourFilter implements Filter {
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)  throws ServletException { }
  public void destroy() { }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // whatever you want to do before doPost

    chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

    // whatever you want to do after doPost
}
```

You'll then need to set up `filter` and `filter-mapping` [in your web.xml](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). If you're using a Servlet 3.x container (like Tomcat 7+), you can [use annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets006.htm).

Comment: Java 6 has annotations. However, only Servlet 3 supports the `@WebFilter`.

Comment: Be careful here. The filter will be activated when processing GET and other kind of requests as well.